# How to scrape an exact class name for the tags in Python?

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am a beginner in Python, I've task to do a web scraping on a Job Portal. I will attach the pictures below. The class name is exactly same for both different tags. I want to have the location class name output and salary class name output. But when I execute, it will show the location only for both class name. Is there any solution for my problem? Do my code has any error?

Here is the Inspect for the website:

[image]

Here is my coding:

```py
job_location = card.find('span','FYwKg _3MPd_ _2Bz3E And8z').text
job_location
try:
    job_salary = card.find('span','FYwKg _2Bz3E C6ZIU_0 _1_nER_0 _2DNlq_0 sQuda_0').text
    if job_salary:
        salary = job_salary
    else:
        salary = 'no salary defined'
except AttributeError:
    salary = 'no salary defined'
```

Comment: Use `job_location = card.select('.FYwKg _3MPd_ _2Bz3E And8z')` and then in next line `job_location.text`. Use select instead of find

Comment: Can you share URL?